# How to copy in Angular 2 only specific fields object into another object

Tags: javascript, angular, copy, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

is there a method to fill a local object in Angular 2 without deleting some attributes? For example, I have a `A` object:

```
export class A {
    first: string;
    second: string;
}
```

Then I get a response like this in `B`:

```
{
    "first": "bob"
}
```

Now I how to do something like that:

```
public a: A; // first and second are undefined
// Retrievethe response in b
this.a = b; // **Without doing fields for fields**
```

But `b` has no `second` attribute, so now `a` object has no more the `second` attribute but I have that it is `undefined`. I see that for forms there is `patchvalue` method, but it's valid only for forms...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

does this help

```
   export class A {
        first?: string;
        second?: string;
    }

    b = new A({
        "first": "bob"
    });

    public a = new A();
```

you can copy value one obj to anther via two way

```
    1. you can assign value directly 

 this.a = this.b;

    2.you can assign value using this method

       Object.assign(a, b);
```

Comment: Hi, when I define a with public a: A; a is undefined, so with assign I get "Cannot convert undefined or null to object"... any workaround?

Comment: Thanks, in this simple case woks but not in my specific case where I have an array. With Object.assign(myArray, newArray); I don't know why but empty fileds are deleted.

Comment: can you create plunker?

Comment: Hi, I notice that the problem is in the constructor... more info in the code: https://plnkr.co/edit/oBVsqsJ50A6cCqpCtY7f?p=preview

Comment: its working well. what you trying to achieve?  see updated plunk

Comment: uhm ok, if I use firstClass.myArray[0].num in an input model I have no problems, the value is updated.. what if I want send "num" with undefined if the user don't use the input model? Why constructors not working well?

Comment: your constructor working fine. but when you assign second class into first class that time its removed bcz its replace it. and num field haven't into second class. its problem. see mu plunk. i console two times you got different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155415/discussion-between-shailesh-ladumor-and-hazlo8).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing instance of A then you can do

```
Object.assign(a, b);
```

And it will copy over only the properties defined in b. If you don't already have an instance of A but just want the properties to be defined as null before copying the values of B then have a function somewhere that creates a default instance of A which just assigns all its values to null.

Answer (score 0):

Define as optional parameter and assign directly

> define as interface not as class

.

```
export interface A {
  first?: string;
  second?: string;
}
```

Now you can assign directly even any of parameter missing

```
{
"first": "bob"
}

public a: A; 
this.a = b;
```

Comment: Hi, when define public a: A;  a is undefined, so I lost the second field...

Comment: "when define public a: A; a is undefined, so I lost the second field" whats that mean??

Comment: If I have:"export interface A {
  first?: string;
  second?: string;
}". Now in your code you have write: public a: A; this.a = b; ".  After the first line (public a: A;) a is undefined, so on the second line (this.a = b;) b overwrite the undefined a, I never had "second" field..

Comment: Assigning Interface will not change anything in the variable. Interface is just defenition about that variable this.a. It will  be undefined unless until you assign something in this. This is what nature of JS

Comment: Why i asked you to mention in optional parameter means, Compiler will not give error on this assignment case